# Can mouse be used as paintbrush with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like an onclick event to overlay the coordinate the user clicks in a figure with a certain colour.

Note:

I do not want to actually edit the picture. This is only on the displayed figure, as an indicative measure of where the user has clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adpat the LineBuilder example on the matplotlib [event handling tutorial page](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class LineBuilder:
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.line = line
        self.xs = list(line.get_xdata())
        self.ys = list(line.get_ydata())
        self.cid = line.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self)

    def __call__(self, event):
        print('click', event)
        if event.inaxes!=self.line.axes: return
        self.xs.append(event.xdata)
        self.ys.append(event.ydata)
        self.line.set_data(self.xs, self.ys)
        self.line.figure.canvas.draw()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('click to add points')
line, = ax.plot([], [], linestyle="none", marker="o", color="r")
linebuilder = LineBuilder(line)

plt.show()
```